# BASH Wild-card : Select all variables (not the content)

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of variables that I want to check, and if they contain the value "None" then I want to empty them.

```
    var1=(check for some value, sometimes it returns "none")
    var2=(check for some value, sometimes it returns "none")
    var3=(check for some value, sometimes it returns "none")
    someBizzareName=(check for some value, sometimes it returns "none")

    if [[ "${var1}" == "None" ]] ; then
        var1=""
    fi
    if [[ "${var2}" == "None" ]] ; then
        var2=""
    fi
```

And this is all working fine and dandy, only since I have *a lot* of varN, I will end up with a ton of `if [[ "${varN}" == "None" ]]` **and** I have to know their names ; so I was wondering, since it's in BASH very nature to search and match everything, if there is a wild-card for variables, **inside a for loop**, that will match *all* vars, something like `${*}` (I tried that, does'nt work) ? I have done all kinds of searches but always find something about matching variable *content*, not the var itself..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*All*, no. But you can match a pattern (but not `*`).

```
$ echo "${!B*}"
BASH BASHOPTS BASHPID BASH_ALIASES BASH_ARGC BASH_ARGV BASH_CMDS BASH_COMMAND BASH_LINENO BASH_SOURCE BASH_SUBSHELL BASH_VERSINFO BASH_VERSION
```

Comment: Hey this works :) It looks like regular [regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) syntax, so something like `[A-Z][0-9]` should work ; **and** it's local to my for loop ; Thanks !

Comment: Ah, thank you Ignacio. Makes my life easier on searching how can I match the end of the string instead of the beginning.

Comment: Ah, [found it](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) :)

Comment: What's the purpose of the ! (3rd char, before the B) in the quoted expression? Also how do you replace * with numbers... say single digit 1-9 doesn't work with "{!B[1-9]}"

Comment: @Nik: The "!" tells it to look for variables with that prefix. The "*" is not negotiable.

Comment: How to get suffix expansion? I can only find `${!prefix*}`

Comment: @BhargavKatkam: You don't.

Comment: Any other solution to get variables with a given suffix?

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the builtin compgen:

```
man bash | less -p 'compgen .option. .word.'
compgen -A variable B
```

Answer (score 1):

All, yes ;-)

Most Unix/Linux support either the `env` or `printenv` which produce output like

```
 var=value
```

The `export` command, without arguments, will list all exported variables in your environment.

```
for varAndVal in $( env ) ; do
   case ${varAndVal} in
     *=none ) 
      eval \$${varAndVal}=
      #OR eval unset \$${varAndVal}
     ;;
    esac
 done
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: This does not quite do what I want ; It matches (really just lists them) environment vars, when I want not only to match vars local to my script (obviously) but if possible, local to my for loop, just to be safe

Comment: Yes, sorry, missed the part about for loop. Good luck!